# How to save the content of a EditText into a String? Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have already tried with:

```
EditText edText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String str = edText1.getText().toString();
```

I only get numbers but not characters.
How can I get the EditText text in order to put it on a string and manipulate it?

Comment: Code looks correct - is your question about the inputType of the EditText? Can u post the XML snippet where `editText1` is defined, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
// first set the Input type of the EditText in the Java class like this;

EditText edText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

String str = edText1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: The thing is that the user does not use the keyboard, he uses buttons (their function consist in making a String in order to set the text on the EditText).

Comment: @tallito Do you mean like this  `edText1.setText(edText1.getText()+"string");`? maybe more code?

Comment: if (id == R.id.button0){
    str = edText1.getText().toString()+'A';
    }
That is an example of how I make the String.
I would like to get the string from edText1.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks with button at my project

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createLog("Called method onCreate");

    Button addTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final EditText vEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    addTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enteredText = vEditText.getText().toString();

            if (enteredText.length() > 0){
                String existingText =((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).getText().toString();
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(existingText + (char)10 + (char)13 + enteredText );
                vEditText.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use toString()** and be sure that EditText has an attribute *text* in the XML.

**android:inputType="text"**

Read more about input types here => [android edit text input types](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style)

```
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String editTextData = editText.getText().toString()
```