# log.d or log.wtf or syso all three not showing

Tags: java, android

The input string which I want to store is not getting stored I think.
In another app on the same mobile, logs are shown but not for this one.
also  on touching "search" button toast appears "enter a value to search"..both times if the  first edit text field is empty or not

members.java

```
package com.example.fbt1first;

public class members {
    private String name,city,country;
    private long age,pincode;

    public members() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(long pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
}
```

Main activity:

```
package com.example.fbt1first;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText ename,eage,epin,ecity,ecountry;
    private Button bsubmit,bgetdata;
    members member;
    long maxid;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ename= findViewById(R.id.name_et1);
        ecity= findViewById(R.id.city_et1);
        eage= findViewById(R.id.age_et1);
        ecountry= findViewById(R.id.country_et1);
        epin= findViewById(R.id.pincode_et1);
        bsubmit= findViewById(R.id.submit_b1);
        bgetdata= findViewById(R.id.getdata_b1);
        member = new members();

        bgetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DATA_RETIEVE.class));
            }
        });

        bsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long age = Long.parseLong(eage.getText().toString());
                long pincode = Long.parseLong(epin.getText().toString());

                member.setCity(ecity.getText().toString());
                member.setCountry(ecountry.getText().toString());
                member.setName(ename.getText().toString());
                member.setAge(age);
                member.setPincode(pincode);

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists())
                        {
                            maxid= snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                            maxid++;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                String namee= ename.getText().toString();

                // yha key hr baar ek increment ho jayegii
//                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(String.valueOf(maxid)).push().setValue(member);



                // yha name ke hisab se database pe daal ra
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(namee).push().setValue(member);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/name_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter age"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/age_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter city"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/city_et1"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter pin code"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/pincode_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter country"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/country_et1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit_b1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="get data"
        android:id="@+id/getdata_b1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

DATA_RETIEVE.JAVA file

```
package com.example.fbt1first;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class DATA_RETIEVE extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText name,age,city,country,inputname;
    private Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_retieve);

        inputname= findViewById(R.id.input_name_et1);
        name= findViewById(R.id.nameshow_et1);
        age= findViewById(R.id.ageshow_et1);
        city= findViewById(R.id.cityshow_et1);
        country= findViewById(R.id.countryshow_et1);
        search= findViewById(R.id.search_data_b1);
        inputname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        String input_name_string = inputname.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss "+input_name_string);
        Log.d("length is .............",input_name_string);
        Log.wtf("length is .............",input_name_string);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(input_name_string.length()==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss "+input_name_string);

                    Toast.makeText(DATA_RETIEVE.this,"enter a value to search "+input_name_string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss thissss"+input_name_string);

                    isuserpresent(input_name_string);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void isuserpresent(String input_name_string) {
        Query checkuser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().equalTo(input_name_string);
        checkuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DATA_RETIEVE.this,"data present",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DATA_RETIEVE.this,"data NOT PRESENT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Its XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20sp"
    tools:context=".DATA_RETIEVE">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/input_name_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/nameshow_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/ageshow_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/cityshow_et1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/countryshow_et1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="search"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
        android:id="@+id/search_data_b1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tried options given here: [How to save the content of a EditText into a String? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713473/how-to-save-the-content-of-a-edittext-into-a-string-android), tried invalidate cache and restart.. still not visible.

My `logcat` in verbose
(i had tap on "get data " button on main activity and then entered "aaaa" in the first edittext field...and then here it's logcat)

```
2021-06-12 09:14:48.218 6650-6650/? I/ample.fbt1firs: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-12 09:14:48.240 6650-6650/? E/ample.fbt1firs: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-06-12 09:14:48.274 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/Typeface: Current DefaultTypeface ( default_lgsmartui )
2021-06-12 09:14:48.369 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2021-06-12 09:14:48.369 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-06-12 09:14:48.373 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.373 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.374 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.379 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.418 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/PhoneWindow: windowLightStatusBar : false, disable View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
2021-06-12 09:14:48.443 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/ample.fbt1firs: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-06-12 09:14:48.443 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/ample.fbt1firs: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-06-12 09:14:48.501 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/TouchFilterInputStageHelper: [needTouchEventFilter] Displayid : 0
2021-06-12 09:14:48.502 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/BezellessGripSuppressionFilter: getdisplaysize, x : 1080 y : 2340
2021-06-12 09:14:48.529 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : ce6447e, Ic1977df6c2
    Build Date                       : 10/09/20
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.1.R1.10.00.00.529.107
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-06-12 09:14:48.529 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S P 8.0.12 AArch64
2021-06-12 09:14:48.531 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
2021-06-12 09:14:48.532 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2021-06-12 09:14:48.532 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:218>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2021-06-12 09:14:48.548 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-06-12 09:14:48.582 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@624342c time:6051705
2021-06-12 09:14:50.756 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
2021-06-12 09:14:50.828 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2021-06-12 09:14:50.866 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c8e1937
2021-06-12 09:14:50.883 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/PhoneWindow: windowLightStatusBar : false, disable View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
2021-06-12 09:14:50.912 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/System.out: input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss 
2021-06-12 09:14:50.924 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/TouchFilterInputStageHelper: [needTouchEventFilter] Displayid : 0
2021-06-12 09:14:50.925 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/BezellessGripSuppressionFilter: getdisplaysize, x : 1080 y : 2340
2021-06-12 09:14:50.981 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c8e1937 time:6054104
2021-06-12 09:14:51.545 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
2021-06-12 09:14:51.593 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2021-06-12 09:14:51.603 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/Editor: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
2021-06-12 09:14:51.616 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/Editor: updateCursorsPositions() : layout = hintLayout
2021-06-12 09:14:51.621 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2380 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
2021-06-12 09:14:51.672 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/Editor: updateCursorsPositions() : layout = hintLayout
2021-06-12 09:14:53.364 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=6056480, downTime=6056480, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 } to DecorView@f8ef3a[DATA_RETIEVE]
2021-06-12 09:14:53.438 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=6056557, downTime=6056480, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 } to DecorView@f8ef3a[DATA_RETIEVE]
2021-06-12 09:14:55.630 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
2021-06-12 09:14:55.703 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2021-06-12 09:14:55.708 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/System.out: input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss 
2021-06-12 09:14:55.742 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/TouchFilterInputStageHelper: [needTouchEventFilter] Displayid : 0
2021-06-12 09:14:55.743 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/BezellessGripSuppressionFilter: getdisplaysize, x : 1080 y : 2340
```

For debug:

```
2021-06-12 09:14:48.218 6650-6650/? I/ample.fbt1firs: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-12 09:14:48.240 6650-6650/? E/ample.fbt1firs: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-06-12 09:14:48.274 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/Typeface: Current DefaultTypeface ( default_lgsmartui )
2021-06-12 09:14:48.369 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2021-06-12 09:14:48.369 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-06-12 09:14:48.373 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.373 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.374 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.379 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ample.fbt1firs: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-06-12 09:14:48.418 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/PhoneWindow: windowLightStatusBar : false, disable View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
2021-06-12 09:14:48.443 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/ample.fbt1firs: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-06-12 09:14:48.443 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/ample.fbt1firs: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-06-12 09:14:48.501 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/TouchFilterInputStageHelper: [needTouchEventFilter] Displayid : 0
2021-06-12 09:14:48.502 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/BezellessGripSuppressionFilter: getdisplaysize, x : 1080 y : 2340
2021-06-12 09:14:48.529 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : ce6447e, Ic1977df6c2
    Build Date                       : 10/09/20
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.1.R1.10.00.00.529.107
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-06-12 09:14:48.529 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S P 8.0.12 AArch64
2021-06-12 09:14:48.531 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
2021-06-12 09:14:48.532 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:194>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2021-06-12 09:14:48.532 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:218>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2021-06-12 09:14:48.548 6650-6682/com.example.fbt1first W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-06-12 09:14:48.582 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@624342c time:6051705
2021-06-12 09:14:50.756 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
2021-06-12 09:14:50.828 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2021-06-12 09:14:50.866 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c8e1937
2021-06-12 09:14:50.883 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/PhoneWindow: windowLightStatusBar : false, disable View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
2021-06-12 09:14:50.912 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/System.out: input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss 
2021-06-12 09:14:50.924 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/TouchFilterInputStageHelper: [needTouchEventFilter] Displayid : 0
2021-06-12 09:14:50.925 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/BezellessGripSuppressionFilter: getdisplaysize, x : 1080 y : 2340
2021-06-12 09:14:50.981 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c8e1937 time:6054104
2021-06-12 09:14:51.545 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
2021-06-12 09:14:51.593 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2021-06-12 09:14:51.603 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/Editor: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
2021-06-12 09:14:51.616 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/Editor: updateCursorsPositions() : layout = hintLayout
2021-06-12 09:14:51.621 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2380 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
2021-06-12 09:14:51.672 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first W/Editor: updateCursorsPositions() : layout = hintLayout
2021-06-12 09:14:53.364 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=6056480, downTime=6056480, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 } to DecorView@f8ef3a[DATA_RETIEVE]
2021-06-12 09:14:53.438 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=6056557, downTime=6056480, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 } to DecorView@f8ef3a[DATA_RETIEVE]
2021-06-12 09:14:55.630 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
2021-06-12 09:14:55.703 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2021-06-12 09:14:55.708 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/System.out: input string issssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss 
2021-06-12 09:14:55.742 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first I/TouchFilterInputStageHelper: [needTouchEventFilter] Displayid : 0
2021-06-12 09:14:55.743 6650-6650/com.example.fbt1first D/BezellessGripSuppressionFilter: getdisplaysize, x : 1080 y : 2340
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fbt1first">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Fbt1first">
        <activity android:name=".DATA_RETIEVE"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You need to set `input_name_string = inputname.getText().toString()` inside `onClick` method.

Comment: yes..it worked...but why local scope is necessary sir??@YaMiN

Comment: Because when you're assigning inside `onCreate` in that time `editText` is empty you need to assign it each time click event is listened which is inside `onClick` method.